# undefined reference to dlopen - buildinf for arm

Tags: linux, build, arm, undefined

I installed Sourcery for Windows, prepared makefile and I got some errors like:

```
undefined reference to dlopen
```

Adding "-ldl" fixed the problem. I also want to build the same app on Ubuntu - the same makefile but different compiler - set to "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.6". I got the same errors.
Maybe on Ubuntu I'm using x86 instead of arm lib. So I removed the "-ldl" param and added:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libdl.a
```

after sources - still the same problem. So maybe I need to add also .so file:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libdl.so
```

It didn't help. Any ideas? Maybe I should use different lib?

Make file looks like:

```
CXX       = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.6
SOURCES   = file.cpp
LIB       = ##
SOLIB     = ##

CFLAGS    = ##
LFLAGS    = -lrt
#-ldl #commented to add the paths manually

SOFLAGS   = ##

test:   $(SOURCES)
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(LFLAGS) /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libdl.a /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libdl.so $(SOFLAGS) -o test
```

Comment: Have you tried `-L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ -ldl` ?

Comment: Also, GNU linker may be sensible to the order of arguments, try to swap some (like main objects and libraries).